# How to install GNU parallel (noarc.rpm) on CentOS 7

Tags: rpm, centos7, gnu-parallel

I want to install GNU parrallel on Centos 7
There is not much info to find. Can someone explain me how to do this?
This is some [useful info](http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/cern/centos/7/cern/x86_64/repoview/parallel.html) I found

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 10 seconds installation is:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

It will download the script `pi.dk/3` and execute it. The script basically does what it says in GNU Parallel's README, so if you feel uncomfortable by executing it directly, download the script and look at it before executing it. Or simply follow the README.

It will install the newest version of GNU Parallel, but it will not install it as a package.

Comment: I tried it but I get this:
The signature on .tar.bz2 is wrong. This may indicate that a criminal has changed the code.
THIS IS BAD AND THE CODE WILL NOT BE INSTALLED.

any solution?

Comment: It looks like a bug. What is the output of `gpg --with-fingerprint *.tar.bz2.sig`?

Comment: gpg: can't open `*.tar.bz2.sig'

Comment: Lets move this to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101793/gnu-parallel-ec2

Comment: Do you also get: `perl: command not found`? If so: Install perl, rm -rf para*, and try again.

Comment: yum install -y autoconf automake perl wget bzip2 cmake freetype-devel gcc gcc-c++ git libtool make nasm pkgconfig && (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - pi.dk/3) | bash

Comment: autoconf, automake, cmake, gcc*, git, libtool, make, nasm, freetype*, and pkgconfig are technically not needed to install GNU Parallel. wget, bzip2 and perl are. make is also needed if you want to do a full installation.

Comment: Small reminder for `zsh` users: after performing `bash install.sh` we need to do either a `source ~/.zsh` or just launch a new terminal session for the changes to be picked

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, 
Download from  http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/parallel/

Tar to new folder , build and install it.

Here is steps to install GNU on Centos

https://medium.com/@gchandra/simple-tutorial-to-install-use-gnu-parallel-79251120d618

Answer (score -1):

You can use gsrc (https://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/) to do that.
Just like 'hello' example given on that page, except replace name with 'parallel'.